# Twig "in" operator with SimpleXMLElement and keys array

Tags: arrays, xml, twig, simplexml

Here I have an issue matching an SimpleXMLElement attribute "name" matching keys in an array. When I dump the result of the attribute matching the string key by calling the array's key, the result is true as expected. But when I try to let it match by using the *in* operator, the result is false.

Twig:

```
{{ dump(options|keys) }}
{% for tense in verbXML %}
{{ dump(tense.attributes.name) }}
{{ dump(tense.attributes.name == (options|keys)[1]) }}
{{ dump(tense.attributes.name in options|keys) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Result:

```
   array:2 [▼
      0 => "neg-imperative"
      1 => "present"
    ]

    SimpleXMLElement {#835 ▼
      +"0": "present"
    }

    true

    false
```

Comment: can you try to force casting on `tense.attributes.name`, something like `(tense.attributes.name ~ '') in options|keys`

Comment: I'm just looking through questions without an answer. Please create an answer yourself and mark it as accepted. Otherwise this question will remain on the "questions without an answer" list for ever, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alain Tiemblo suggested, using `(tense.attributes.name ~ '') in options|keys` was the answer. Thank you!